# VLCJ Java Applet will not load

Tags: java, applet, vlcj

I am trying to compile a vlcj application into a java applet. I have the 3 jar files needed for vlcj to run in `/lib`. And my class file in`/src`. In eclipse, the applet works fine in the applet viewer. But when I package the jar file and load up my test html page. Nothing happens! I know the applet requires being signed due to the sand-boxing of java applets. And have signed the applet but I surely must be doing something wrong.

These are the steps I make:

1) So to create the applet first I compile the .java file to a .class file and store the .class file in `/bin.`

`javac -cp lib/vlcj-2.1.0.jar:lib/platform-3.4.0.jar:lib/jna-3.4.0.jar Test.java`

2) I then create my jar file with

`jar cvf Test.jar lib/* Test.class`

3) I then generate the keys with:`keytool`

4) I then sign the `Test.jar` file with `jarsigner` to produce `SignedTest.jar`.

5) I then Export the public key to certificate

6) and then import that certificate as a trusted certificate.

My Test html page open the java applet with:

`<applet code="bin/Test.class" archive="SignedTest.jar” width=200 height=200>`

Are any of these steps wrong? Am I missing a stage or two? 
And a bonus question? Anyone know how to get console output in linux?

--- Edit ---

This is the structure of the Signed Jar File.

```
   703 Wed Aug 22 09:25:16 BST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   908 Wed Aug 22 09:25:16 BST 2012 META-INF/SIGNFILE.SF
   782 Wed Aug 22 09:25:16 BST 2012 META-INF/SIGNFILE.DSA
   500 Wed Aug 22 09:06:28 BST 2012 Test$1.class
  1448 Wed Aug 22 09:06:28 BST 2012 Test.class
    40 Tue Aug 14 11:36:48 BST 2012 Notes
1008730 Tue Jul 10 13:15:48 BST 2012 lib/jna-3.4.0.jar
913436 Tue Jul 10 13:15:48 BST 2012 lib/platform-3.4.0.jar
278211 Tue Jul 10 13:15:48 BST 2012 lib/vlcj-2.1.0.jar
   371 Tue Jul 10 13:23:54 BST 2012 .project
   351 Tue Jul 10 13:16:18 BST 2012 .classpath
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1) No, Class wasn't in a package called bin. I didn't realise that was the package name. I since dropped the bin so `code="Test"` and still no luck.2) Yep deploying an applet that relies is on vlc is fragile. I haven't heard of Xuggle, I will have a look. I need something that supports access multicast mpeg streams. I will see if this supports it. 3) Yes the dialog for accepting the signed code appears and I do click yes. 4) I am currently running this on Ubuntu and haven't got the Java Console to appear for applets yet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Lots googling and I have a Java Console. Now i am confused. The console says:
`basic: exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/co/caprica/vlcj/component/EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.`

This a class stored in one of the external jar. What did you mean by those Jars will need to be in the run-time class-path. Is this the html code or do i need to change the `.classpath` file? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/co/caprica/vlcj/component/EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.
```

The Jar containing `uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` needs to be added to the run-time class-path of the applet.  That is achieved via the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.  It should be a comma delimited list of Jars that are required for the applet.  Based on the compilation details and assuming they are all in the same directory as the HTML, might lead to this applet element.

```
<applet 
    code="Test" 
    archive="SignedTest.jar,vlcj-2.1.0.jar,platform-3.4.0.jar,jna-3.4.0.jar" 
    width=200 
    height=200>
</applet>
```

Comment: It worked but this time I had a different error. But as my applet loaded I think it is safe to say the original problem is solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"It worked.."* Glad you got it sorted.  *"..this time I had a different error"*  If you cannot solve the error, feel free to post another question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Test.class never gets added to the .jar file? Because Eclipse puts the .class file into /bin/Test.class, and you are trying to add /Test.class

To check, try

```
    jar tvf Test.jar
```

after step 2.

Try using Eclipse to create the Jar. File | Export | Java | Jar file.

Comment: I didn't know about jar tvf, thanks for letting me know. Bit new to java. I did it and the Test.class is there. I also hadn't thought of using Eclipse to create the jar.

I used Eclipse to create the jar this time. The jar file had Test.class & the 3 are jar files i required. I remove the bin from my html code and gave it a shot. no luck either.

Comment: Well the .jar file within a .jar file is probably not any use. That's why (in your solution) you had to specify the .jar files in the archive= attribute of the applet tag. JAR files must be on the classpath to be found by the Java Classloader.